# Return all rows where col matches that of the counted top 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count how many times a `productID` is listed, and then use that to return all rows where the `productID` matches that of the counted top 2.

So take this table:

```
ID | productID
1  | 2 
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 3
5  | 4
6  | 2
```

The query would return:

```
ID | productID
1  | 2
2  | 2
6  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 3
```

I do not want to use a `LIMIT` because I don't know how many rows will be returned, and I need to grab them all.

I want to write the query in a way that I can use an offset to grab the next top 2 (so 3-4, and then 5-6, etc.)

I'm not entirely sure this is possible with SQL alone, the best I've come up with is:

```
SELECT ID, productID, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, productID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.productId in (select t2.productId
                      from t t2
                      group by productId
                      order by count(*) desc
                      limit 2
                     )
order by t.productId;
```

If you want to use the count in the query (say for ordering), then use a subquery in the `from` clause ("derived table") instead:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t2.productId, count(*) as cnt
      from t t2
      group by productId
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 2
     ) tt
     on t.productId = tt.productId
order by count(*) desc, id;
```

And finally, if you just want the ids for the top two, then perhaps aggregating them into an array is sufficient:

```
select t2.productId, array_agg(id) as ids
from t t2
group by productId
order by count(*) desc
limit 2;
```

This would return:

```
productID    ids
    2        {1,2,6}
    3        {3,4}
```

Comment: Plus one for the solution with `array_agg`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find count per productId and find dense rank on it and filter to get only top 2 rank based on the count:

```
select
    id, productId
from (
    select
        t.*,
        dense_rank() over (order by cnt desc) rnk
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            count(*) over (partition by productId) cnt
        from your_table t
    ) t
) t where rnk <= 2
order by cnt desc, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From table t
where productId In
   (Select productId from table
    group by productId
    order by count<*> desc
    limit 2)
```